# "Launchpad doesn't understand the form data submitted in this request." when using links

Tags: launchpad

If I use the console/text browser `links` to access https://launchpad.net I experience the error `Launchpad doesn't understand the form data submitted in this request.` after sending the form of an advanced search the second time (the first time causes the advanced search page to be displayed without a change).

I'd like to know whether I'm doing something wrong and if not if that's more likely a `links` or a launchpad.net bug.

Here's what I'm doing (100 % reproducible) when searching for `black screen` sorted by date:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If I want to `apport-collect` data in the recovery mode I get the error `Bad bot, go away! Request aborted.` in `links` after logging in to authorize the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a `links` bug.  Rather than making the query string for the `GET` request that happens when you press "Search" be just the URL-encoded contents of the search form, which is how it's supposed to work, `links` instead submits a form that consists of the query string it started with *plus* the URL-encoded contents of the search form.  This means that:

1. the first time round, you get the search form again because `advanced=1` is still set, which is the parameter that causes Launchpad to show the search form;
2. the second time round, it sends all the search parameters from the first attempt and then all the same search parameters again, which causes Launchpad to fail because it was only expecting a single value for some of those inputs.

The current HTML specification defines the [form submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#form-submission-algorithm), and makes it clear that the browser is to *set* the query string to the encoded form, not append the encoded form.

Feel free to [file a Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+filebug) as well; it would be low-priority because it seems to be just this browser, but there may be some way we can produce clearer errors and/or construct the form in such a way as to avoid this browser bug (for example, I suspect that using `action="/+bugs"` rather than `action=""` would work around it).  It would be best to send a bug report to the [links developer](http://links.twibright.com/development.php) though, since it seems to be actively maintained; please CC me (cjwatson@canonical.com) and I can help explain the situation.